# Producer-Consumer: Should I synchronize read access

Tags: scala, synchronization

Consider the producer-consumer problem, with ONE producer and several consumers. The consumers wait until they are told a value has been produced. The producer writes a value and notifies all consumers, who then read the value. Finally: The consumers' and producer's termination is synchronized using a barrier. The process repeats.

Question: Should I provide exclusive access (e.g. synchronized) to reading the value for the consumers (or writing for producer?). I know the obvious answer is: "Seriously? NO!" but I just want to make sure I am not missing any weird detail.

Comment: The message is sent to all consumers, but is the value accessible to each consumers or only to the first one which can read it ? How values are deleted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a concurrent application, I recommend you investigate Akka. It has much to offer and is not trivial to learn, but it is pretty comprehensive as far as concurrency and distribution.

For your particular case, its data-flow variables might suit your needs (and free you from overt synchronization!)